# How can we upload json data to firebase realtime database

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can we upload json data in firebase realtime database in android. I have some unique json data per user which i want to upload it to realtime database and then retrive them also.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is documented in the official docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/
WIthout any information about your data, or from where you want to upload it, I would use toString() to create a string from the json and save this string

Comment: Have you tried to upload it using the Firebase Console?

Comment: thanks for your comment. actually i want to get all the phone contacts of the user and convert it to json and then upload it to realtime database . from which i would like to get back the json data when required.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to use the firebase storage instead of realtimeDatabase, there you can freely upload all documents you want. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start